# Make the side div follow after certain scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now the div on the right follows the scroll all the time. If I want it to start following the scroll when the page is scrolled to the top of the div, and make it remain there when scrolled up, what more do I need to do?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zreh4ek/2/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.mSidebar').css( "top", scrollTop + 400 );
    console.log(scrollTop);
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you´d like to fix the div if the scrollbar is on top of the screen, right? Should the div then stay there, or, if the users moves the scrollbar again should the div also be moved. Should de div only be fixed if the user scrolls from lower the top to the top of the page or are there other cases to. Can you explain your requirements more detailed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
            var newPos = $(document).scrollTop() + 400 ;
            $('.mSidebar').css( {top:newPos});
        }

        else {
            $('.mSidebar').css( {top:400});
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yours worked perfectly. Except I needed to change the top:newPos + 400 to top:newPos

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` when you want something to stick to the top (or bottom).

```
    //you can do it in initial layout, no need to set up css in js
    $('.mSidebar').css( "position", 'fixed');


    //if user scrolled down more then 400 px we make div to stick to the top
    if (scrollTop>400) {
        $('.mSidebar').css( "top", 0);
    } else {
        //otherwise it stays in the middle of the screen
        $('.mSidebar').css( "top", '400px');
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4zreh4ek/6/

Answer (score 0):

You use position:fixed when the scroll comes to the position of your choice. This is triggered by the scroll event.

BUT! make sure that the div resets when it gets back to <400 scroll. Here is an example I have drawn up.

Hope this Helps!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 if (scroll > 400) {
   $('.mSidebar').css("position", "fixed");
    $('.mSidebar').css("top", 5);
  } else {
   $('.mSidebar').css("position", "absolute");
    $('.mSidebar').css("top", 400);
  }
});
```

```css
.mSidebar {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  right: 20px;
}

body {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
  <div class="mSidebar"></div>
</body>
```